# Haskell foldr algrebraic datatypes

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I have solved all issues I had with functions but one is left.

The foldr function works from last element to the first one and I need to get the data in the other order

```
module QueueFunctor where

import Test.HUnit (runTestTT,Test(TestLabel,TestList,TestCase),(~?=))
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldr)

data DQueue a = Empty | Enqueue a (DQueue a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance Foldable DQueue
  where
    foldr _ result Empty = result 
    foldr f result (Enqueue x xs) = foldr f (f x result) xs


-- | Tests a few examples.
main :: IO ()
main = do
    testresults <- runTestTT tests
    print testresults


sample1 :: DQueue Int
sample1 =  Enqueue 1 $ Enqueue 2 $ Enqueue 3 $ Enqueue 4 Empty

sample2 :: DQueue String
sample2 = Enqueue "a" $ Enqueue "b" $ Enqueue "c" $ Enqueue "d" Empty

tests :: Test
tests = TestLabel "DQueueTest" (TestList [
        foldr (++) "" sample2 ~?= "abcd"
    ])
```

When I compile the program, I get one error regarding tests:

```
### Failure in: DQueueTest:1
QueueFunctors.hs:56
expected: "abcd"
 but got: "dcba"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not use `foldl`?

Comment: There was a strict rule in the description of the task to use foldr.

Comment: Your `foldr` definition looks like it's actually `foldl`. That would explain the reversed results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this definition of `foldr` for lists, which is used for the list instance of `Foldable`.

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ z []     =  z
foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Now consider that your data type is isomorphic to a list.

```
data DQueue a = Empty | Enqueue a (DQueue a)

toList :: Dqueue a -> [a]
toList Empty = []
toList (Enqueue x xs) = x : toList xs

fromList :: [a] -> Dqueue a
fromList [] = Empty
fromList (x:xs) = Enqueue x (fromList xs)
```